# Could we plant enough trees to offset greenhouse gas emissions?

Tags: climate-change, carbon-cycle, greenhouse-gases

In 2014, [the world emitted 10 billion metric tonnes of carbon dioxide](https://www.epa.gov/ghgemissions/global-greenhouse-gas-emissions-data). A [50 year old oak tree forest sequesters 30,000 pounds of CO2 per acre](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/12/04/science/how-many-pounds-of-carbon-dioxide-does-our-forest-absorb.html). At that rate of sequestration per acre, offsetting all carbon emissions would require [735 million new acres of trees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(10*10%5E9%20metric%20tons)%20%2F%2030000%20pounds%20per%20acre), which sounds like a lot but is only [about 2% of the world's total land area](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=735%20million%20acres%20%2F%20((Land%20area%20of%20earth))). By comparison, Europe is about 1490 million acres, and the United States is 2400 million acres.

Would it be practical / possible to offset global carbon emissions by reforesting 2-3% of the earth's land area, specifically in deforested regions? I know you can't just conjure up a 50 year old oak forest, but by choosing the right species of trees it should be possible.

Comment: Just to correct some of your math.  The chart says global carbon emissions, not CO2.   Carbon has a molecular weight of 12, CO2 of 44, so you need to multiply your estimate by 44/12 which comes to 7.3%.  That's nearly 40% larger than the continental US.  That's a lot of land,